# XML parsing failed in the sqlplus

Tags: xml, oracle, oracle11g, sqlplus

I get following error when executing the query

> Invalid token in '*[count(../*[name(../*)=name(.)])=count(../*) and count(../*)>1'

However when installing the Itstar_xml_util package, it asks for two initial variables one **quot** and another call **gt**, which form the initial structure of the `XML`, I believe that is causing the error, someone knows how to configure correctly?

```
SQL> @C:\instantclient_11_2\itstar_xml_util.pck
     Packge created.
     Enter value for quot: ?
     Enter value for gt: ?
```

Also follow the query...

```
SQL > declare
      l_sql_string varchar2(32000);
      l_xml xmltype;
      l_json xmltype;
      begin
      l_sql_string := 'select DESCRICAO from VEI_TIPO_VEICULO';
      l_xml := itstar_xml_util.sql2xml(l_sql_string);
      dbms_output.put_line(l_xml.getclobval());
      l_json := itstar_xml_util.xml2json(l_xml);
      dbms_output.put_line(l_json.getclobval());
      end;
      /
```

Comment: What is itstar_xml_util.pxk?

Comment: @OldProgrammer Wrong in typing in fact the extention is PCK, is a package to transform the results to XML and JSON

Comment: http://armbruster-it.org/index.php/12-it/pl-sql/12-oracle-xml-and-json-goodies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When installing the package, switch off scanning for the defines...

```
SQL> set define off
SQL> @C:\instantclient_11_2\itstar_xml_util.pck
```

Comment: @FelipeDuarte, you believe well. Thanks.